# How to excute a function in x component from y component?

Tags: angular6

I have a component `alphabatesComponent`. It has a method `postLetters()`. I want to call `wordsComponent` listOfAlphabates() method whenever I call `postLetters()` in `alphabatesComponent`.

// Service

```
private _listners = new Subject<any>();
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

listen(): Observable<any> {
    debugger;
   return this._listners.asObservable();
}

filter(filterBy: string) {
    debugger;
   this._listners.next(filterBy);
}
```

// alphabates component

```
export class alphabatesComponent {
  postLetters(): void {
    this.asynService.filter('Register click');
  }
}
```

// this is my words component

```
constructor() {
this.asyncService.listen().subscribe((m: any) => {
  this.listOfAlphabates();
 }
}
 listOfAlphabates() {}
```

}

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing?

Comment: Please note the ensemble of letters is spelled alphabet in English. All classes should begin with a capital: AlphabetComponent.

Answer (score 0):

for state managment use rxJs:

in alphabates component:

```
filter () {
    this.asynService.onFilterChanged.next('Registerclick');
}
```

in asynService:

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

public onFilterChanged: BehaviorSubject<any> = new 
       BehaviorSubject('');
```

in word component:

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

private onFilterChanged: Subscription;

constructor(public asynService: AsynService,) {

    this.onFilterChanged = this.asynService.onFilterChanged
        .subscribe((filterBy) => {
            this.listOfAlphabates(filterBy);
        });
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // note: Do not forget to unsubscribe!
    this.onFilterChanged.unsubscribe();
}

listOfAlphabates(text) {
    console.log(text);
}
```